# I need to get and display the average of the results between two dates, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been stuck on one problem now for a long while. I have to find a way to display the average amount of movie screenings within a week, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do so. Everything I've looked up can get me the average of the *dates* that appear within a period (converting them into a dataform that can use the average, but not the average of the results.

[ERD Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yeOg.png)

I can find the results between two dates using:

```
SELECT Day(screeningDay) as MovieDay, COUNT(ScreeningDay) as countMovieDay
FROM screening
WHERE Day(ScreeningDay) BETWEEN '20' AND '24'
GROUP BY ScreeningDay
ORDER BY countMovieDay
```

and what I need is get the average of the *results* of that query.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Posting a picture of tables is not really very helpful. What is helpful is data structures and sample data like outlined in this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sample data would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Would selecting the average using a wrapping query work?

```
SELECT Avg(tmp.numScreenings) FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(ScreeningDay) as numScreenings
   FROM screening
   WHERE Day(ScreeningDay) BETWEEN '20' AND '24'
   GROUP BY Day(ScreeningDay)
) as tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average for days when there are movies:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(ScreeningDay))
FROM screening
WHERE Day(ScreeningDay) BETWEEN 20 AND 24;
```

If you want to count days without movies as "0", then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / (24 - 20 + 1)
FROM screening
WHERE Day(ScreeningDay) BETWEEN 20 AND 24;
```

Comment: This did work, thank you very much. For those who might need something like this in future and get a syntax error, there is a missing bracket at the end of:

`COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(ScreeningDay)`